# __attribute__((constructor)) how it change entry point?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I know that from the point of view of the C programming language
`main()` is the entry point of the program.

But from the point of view of the operating system is `__start` at `ctrt0`  startup routines which are linked into a program that performs any initialization work required before calling the program's `main()` function (correct me if wrong here).

So we have some attributes which we can use for our functions, one of them is
constructor attribute which is called before main(), who is responsible to call this function?

```
__attribute__((construtor))
void foo(void)
{
        puts("Constructor called by ... ?\n");
}
```

and how would it look in step by step call stack? Thanks!

Comment: Just to nitpick: It's not the symbol `__start` that is the starting point from the OS point of view. It's the starting point from the *linker scripts* point of view. The linker script will then set up the linker so that it sets a specific field in the header for the executable file to contain the address to whatever "start" function is mentioned in the linker script.

Comment: It's apparently not a standard C feature, so the answer should be clear. And it does not change the **C** program entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions marked as "constructor" are placed in a special section in the executable file. The "start" function will then invoke those functions one by one, before it calls `main`.

The same with "destructor" functions, they are again placed in a special section and called by the code executing after `exit` is called or `main` returns.

Comment: Actually they are not placed into a special section, but their invokation is. IIRC it's the same mechanism used for C++ to call ctors/dtors for static objects (hence the name).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite That makes more sense, since it would be much easier to generate code for.

Comment: I had to look up the exact mechanics, but IIRC there is a glibc function (or user-provided for e.g. embedded systems) which is called by the crt parsing the section data as a list/array or similar. Needs support by the linker, etc of course.